# Site for mobile phone not displaying

Tags: jquery

I spent two days trying to find out what's going with my mobile site since It doesn't display from my HTC sense smartphone. I still see the pc version from my smartphone, but not  the mobile version. I installed a PHP web server, but the mobile site still doesn't display. I tried different code approaches but none of them worked. Can somebody please help me with some ideas?

Also:
My "index.html" page (for mobile site) is located inside a folder called: "mobile" (inside the root folder)
My "index.html" page (for pc site) is located inside the regular root folder.

my standard website is: www.accurateprinting.com/index.html

my mobile page is: http://www.accurateprinting.com/mobile/index.html

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

From console output:

```
Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. index.html:6
Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. index.html:6
Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "maximum-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. index.html:6
Viewport argument value "no;" for key "user-scalable" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. index.html:6
```

I think, you should use , instead a ;

Comment: hm, you not fix this yet... I simple open url above in Chrome and read console warnings. Use comma instead of semicolon in your meta[name=viewport] content attribute `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: mark the answer if it helps you.. And I'm surprised with the feedback time :)

Comment: how do I do that?  vp_arth

Comment: green check near the answer)